# Proxy Routing on Angular App deployed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have an Angular app that is talking to a REST service.

When I run the Angular app local with the CLI, correctly proxies all `/api` requests to the REST service.  When I try to build the app and run through a `server.js` (so that I can deploy the app to `Heroku`) I lose the proxy routing.

The REST service is deployed on Heroku and runs fine.

I run the Angular with:

```sh
ng serve
```

My `proxy.conf.json`

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://my-app.herokuapp.com",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I created a `server.js` as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352) so that I can deploy onto Heroku.

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// If an incoming request uses
// a protocol other than HTTPS,
// redirect that request to the
// same url but with HTTPS
const forceSSL = function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
            return res.redirect(
                ['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join('')
            );
        }
        next();
    }
}
// Instruct the app
// to use the forceSSL
// middleware
app.use(forceSSL());

// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// For all GET requests, send back index.html
// so that PathLocationStrategy can be used

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4200);
```

I also set up a post install build in my `package.json` scripts:

```
{
  "name": "catalog-manager-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^8.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^13.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^3.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.11.2",
    "npm": "6.5.0"
  }
}
```

I am an Angular novice so I could be making a fundamental mistake, but how do I modify the `server.js` to use the `proxy.conf.json` settings?

Comment: did you figure this out? Am in this boat.

Comment: @godhar - I answered my own question below.  Basically you need something to serve the static files that are your compiled code.  If you're using `Koa` you should be able to copy/paste the code below to get started.

Comment: Any solution for node.js based proxy setup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation falls into the **yes, you're making a fundamental mistake** category, but I've seen enough similar questions that I thought an explanation might just help the next dev.

The Angular CLI is running a full http server.  The Angular UI is fully compiled and the CLI is serving it as static content from the `/dist` directory.

The `proxy.conf.json` settings are for **the Server run by the Angular CLI**, it has nothing to do with your compiled code.

When you move from a local environment to something like `Heroku` you need a server to take the place of the Angular CLI.  This is where all the examples of `node.js` and `express` come in.  The simple `server.js` file they walk you through is enough to set up a basic static content server.  And that's fine, because your Angular code is static content!

But if you need routing to a dynamic backend server via a `proxy.conf.json`, well, your simple static server doesn't know anything about that.

In my case, my backend server runs on `Koa`, so I added static routing to the Angular code.

```
const router = require('koa-router')();
const body = require('koa-body')({ text: false });
const send = require('koa-send');
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Code about server routes ommited
 */

async function main(ctx, next) {
    //All dynamic routes start with "/api"
    if (/\/api\//.test(ctx.path)) {
        try {
            await next();
        }
        catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof ApplicationError) {
                logger.error(error, { data: error.data, stack: error.stack });
                ctx.status = error.code;
            } else {
                ctx.status = 500;
                logger.error(error.message, { stack: error.stack });
            }
        }
        return;
    } else {
        //Not a dynamic route, serve static content
        if ((ctx.path != "/") && (fs.existsSync('dist' + ctx.path))) {
            await send(ctx, 'dist' + ctx.path);
        } else {
            await send(ctx, 'dist/index.html');
        }
    }
}

module.exports = app => {
    app.use(main);
    app.use(router.routes());
};
```

**NOTE** - this isn't a performant solution for any kind of high workload, but if you've got a very small project that doesn't justify spending resources setting up something more scalable, this will work until you get bigger.

Comment: awesome! I had a different issue. But this will surely help another.

Comment: @Sherman THis is what i need but im using server.js, so basically i have two apps running on heroku , one a client (angular app) and second server (spring boot) so i have the proxy.conf.json  {
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://mygramapi.herokuapp.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
} But i cant access it from my angular app, it seems to be calling client instead of the server,  ,my server.js  below        in second comment

Comment: //Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/mygram'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +'/src'));
});
console.log(app);
// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);

Answer (score 0):

Any One looking for Implementation of angular application using proxy api on heroku you can use  WebpackDev Server and http-proxy-middleware in server.js

`npm install http-proxy-middleware`

`npm install webpack webpack-dev-server`

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry:'./src/index.js',//no implemenation needed by default webpack verification
    mode: 'development',   
    devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,// handle 404 cannot get error after refreshing url
    https: true,//secure the server
    compress: true,//invalid header multiple url proxy
    client: {
        webSocketURL: 'ws://0.0.0.0:8080/ws',// handle Invalid header error  in heroku port 8080 maps in server.js
      },
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/<app-name>'),
      },

      proxy: {
    /** Same as proxy.conf.json or proxy.conf.js */
        ' /api1/*': {
          target: 'https://<other-heroku-deployed-url>',
          changeOrigin:true,
          secure:false,
          pathRewrite: {
          '^/api1':'https://<other-heroku-deployed-url>/api1'                           },
        }, 
        ' /api2/*': {
          target: 'https://<other-heroku-deployed-url>',
          changeOrigin:true,
          secure:false,
          pathRewrite: {
          '^/api2':'https://<other-heroku-deployed-url>/api2'                           },
        }
      },
    },
   
  };
```

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const app = express();

const Webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
/** this is custom js to help proxy in server.js*/
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');


const compiler = Webpack(webpackConfig);
const devServerOptions = { ...webpackConfig.devServer, open: true };
const server = new WebpackDevServer(devServerOptions, compiler);

const runServer = async () => {
  console.log('Starting server...');
  await server.start();
};

runServer();
/** If you have error creating proxy <app-url> to localhost  
 * Heroku internally redirect the Server port 8080 .
 *  For that reason we need to open listener  port(I used 3000 here) redirect 
through http-proxy-middleware*/
 app.use("/*", createProxyMiddleware(
    { target: "https://localhost:8080", 
    ws: true ,
     changeOrigin: true,
     secure:false,
     router: {
    'dev.localhost:3000': 'https://localhost:8080',
  },})) 

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

`npm start` or `node server.js`